# How to distinguish multiple OS X installations from each other in the bootloader?

Tags: macos, startup

I read with interest [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49585/set-up-flash-drive-with-multiple-os-x-installers) about setting up a flash drive with multiple OS X installers.  It confirms what I've suspected by my tests with just one OS (Lion).

However, a question occurred to me:
How do you avoid multiple instances of "Mac OS X" appearing as possible boot choices?  In other words, how do you know which one is which?

EDIT:  I am referring to the situation when booting with the "Option" key held down, showing all available boot sources.

- Does the boot loader distinguish between them somehow?
- If not, can I (safely) rename the string in the "SystemVersion.plist" file on each partition?

Comment: Similar: [How can I change the title of a boot image?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2350/8546) – whilst the question is oriented to Snow Leopard, the accepted answer may be good for you.

Answer (score 1):

- Get a 16gb or 32gb usb stick
- Partition it with GPT (to have EFI partition on it) if you trying to install os x on non apple hardware = hackintosh use MBR and manually add an EFI partition (EFI specification says it can live with mbr as well)
- restore InstallESD.dmg with Disk Utility to a partition for each Installer Image you wish. Just make sure your partitions have at least 5gb space.

Your partition table on your USB stick could look like this

/dev/diskX1 - EFI

/dev/diskX2 - Osx Lion

/dev/diskX3 - Osx Mountain Lion

/dev/diskX4 - Osx Snow Leopard

/dev/diskX5 - Osx Whatever

install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) on the usb sticks EFI Partiotion to have a boot loader. EFI Partitions are 200mb, named EFI, filesystem type is FAT to check if you got one on your usb stick enter in terminal 
`diskutil list` and look for EFI in the lists, shoud be '/dev/diskX**s1**' since it's the first partition on GPT based tables

if trying to use install OS x on non Apple Hardware (==osx86) use [Clover V2](http://projectosx.com) instead of Refit. Put your Usb into your computer and boot from it. If you don't see a boot menu on Mac after installing refit - read the readme file and bless the disk from terminal.

Be happy with your uber usb installer

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it for a long time, but it didn't distinguish them in any way.

If you want an easy way of clearly setting them apart, you could just change the default *Macintosh HD* name of the HD (just by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, no need to change any *.plist*).

Comment: How does that change the names in the boot loader screen?  I agree that renaming the volumes would make a difference if I were to use the System Prefs to choose the startup volume.  The problem there is that assumes the system is even bootable.

Comment: Well, it will work if each bootable source is in a different partition.

Comment: They are in different partitions, in fact they have to be, given the recommended method of creating them in the first place.  I asked about the .plist file because I found the ID string used to name the things and figured that it might be the only way of forcing them to be different.  I'll give your suggestion a try when I get a key large enough to hold 10.6, 10.7 and the upcoming 10.8.